# Building A Basic Friends System: Get All Friends Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

So I have these two tables:

```
user table:
id, username
10, hovercraft
11, mine_craft

friendship table:
id, user_id, friend_id
1,  10,      11
```

now I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT `friends`.`id`, 
 `friends`.`username`, 
FROM `users` AS `u` 
JOIN `friendships` AS `fs` 
ON (`fs`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`) 
JOIN `users` AS `friends` 
ON (`friends`.`id` = `fs`.`friend_id`) 
WHERE `fs`.`user_id` = '10' 
OR  `fs`.`friend_id` = '10'
```

in where I want to get the friends for a particular user_id. However, this query cannot create a "2-way" retrieval, for when I provide user_id 11, no friends show up.

Is there a way I can get around this?

**EDIT**: I forgot to add that friend_id also references id in user table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Added**, better version (I think):

```
select u.id, username
from user u
left join friendship f1 on u.id = f1.user_id
left join friendship f2 on u.id = f2.friend_id
where coalesce(f1.friend_id, f2.user_id, u.id) <> u.id and
    coalesce(f1.friend_id, f2.user_id, u.id) = 10
```

than this query (placed as first):

```
select id, username from (
    select u.id, username, case when f.friend_id <> u.id then f.friend_id else f.user_id end as friend_id
    from user u
    join friendship f on u.id = f.user_id
    union
    select u.id, username, case when f.friend_id <> u.id then f.friend_id else f.user_id end as friend_id
    from user u
    join friendship f on u.id = f.friend_id
) t where friend_id = 10
```

Comment: this is awesome, though it's the first time I have used COALESCE. I will take time to study it :D

Answer (score 1):

You're starting your query a little too deep. Since the friendships table has a field that you can look for the user id in, then start the query there and only join the users table to select the friends:

```
SELECT u."id", u."username"
FROM "friendships" AS f
JOIN "users" AS u ON f.friend_id = u."friend_id"
WHERE f."user_id" = 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution : the difficulty lies in the correct request because friend requests can be crossed (if A asks B or B asks A will be stored the opposite way in the "to" and "from" fields of the table). Lets do it like that and user UNION and aliases to get friends from any user independently of the relation table bellow.

1. The [friends] table (relation): to|from|statut(pending,confirmed)
2. "to" and "from" > foreign_keys constraint to a [users] table

The request below always gives the wanted results ! (replace %d by the user ID or user Id in the SESSION

```
SELECT
    users.userNickname,
    friends.to AS friendUser,
    friends.from AS currentUser,
    friends.statut
    FROM
    users
        INNER JOIN
        friends
        ON
        users.userId = friends.to
    WHERE
    friends.from = '%d' 
UNION
    SELECT
    users.userNickname,
    friends.from AS friendUser,
    friends.to AS currentUser,
    friends.statut
    FROM
    users
        INNER JOIN
        friends
        ON
        users.userId = friends.from
    WHERE
    friends.to = '%d'
```